# Show a new DIV foreach Array every second with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a new div every second with a prefilled data from the array list.

fields.php:

```
<?php

$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
    $names = $line;
    echo $names[array_rand($names)];
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

JS:

```
<script>
function createName(){
    var feedback = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fields.php",
        async: false
    }).complete(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){get_fb_complete();}, 1000);
    }).responseText;

    $('.content').html(feedback);
}

$(function(){
    createName();
});
</script>
```

And the Div I want to be created with the data from the arrays:

```
    <div class="content">

    <div class="col-1">

    <div class="profile-bg">
    <div class="inside-profile">
    <img src="img/avatars/avatar1.jpg" class="img-circle" border="0"></img>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="details">
    <p style="font-size: 18px;"> ==*I want to show an ARRAY here.== </p>
    <p class="details-desc"> ==*(TIMESTAMP, something like: 1m to show when this div was created)== </p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
    <img src="img/userImg/userImg1.jpg" class="viewed-img" border="0"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
<div class="seperator"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

How to transform each ARRAY created in fields.php into a `.content` DIV?

Comment: for example if the printed values at the php is "a", "b", "c"
you need this <p style="font-size: 18px;"> ==*I want to show an ARRAY here.== </p>
to be 
<p style="font-size: 18px;">
<div class="content">a</div>
<div class="content">b</div>
<div class="content">c</div>
</p>
correct ?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to print the value in a JSON format from the php side

```
<?php

$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');
$data = [];
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
    $names = $line;
    $data[] = $names[array_rand($names)];
}
fclose($file);
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

assuming values was a,b,c it will print `["a","b","c"]`

at the js we will parse this values and iterate over it

```
<script>
function createName(){
    var feedback = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fields.php",
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            // parse json 
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            // add them in divs
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++ )
            {
                // create the required format - you can do the same with createElement and assign class also
                var item_code = "<div class='content'>"+data[i]+"</div>";
                $("#container_p").append(item_code);
            }
        }
    }).complete(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){get_fb_complete();}, 1000);
    }).responseText;

    $('.content').html(feedback);
}

$(function(){
    createName();
});
</script>
```

Last thing is the HTML part just add id for the container p

```
    <div class="content">

    <div class="col-1">

    <div class="profile-bg">
    <div class="inside-profile">
    <img src="img/avatars/avatar1.jpg" class="img-circle" border="0"></img>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="details">
    <p style="font-size: 18px;" id="container_p"></p>
    <p class="details-desc"> ==*(TIMESTAMP, something like: 1m to show when this div was created)== </p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
    <img src="img/userImg/userImg1.jpg" class="viewed-img" border="0"></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
<div class="seperator"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: i think this is because of ".complete" please replace it with ".always" instead

Comment: Sorry I didn't replied, I was sleeping. I've changed what you suggested and now there is no error but there is nothing happening on the site either....

Comment: Never mind, sorry too there was a spilling error, at the JS it is "success" not "sucess" , i updated the answer

Comment: It seems like it posts the whole ARRAY's list, anyway to post one of them every second? Also with `.complete` the code gives the result ones but with `.always` it keeps adding the result every second. So for my purpose i'd better use `.always`. So the only problem is that it posts the whole list of ARRAY's instead of one by one: http://take.ms/2XYSg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123943/discussion-between-ricardo-and-amr-magdy).

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file MUST BE CHANGED to give you only ONE LINE FROM THE FILE at each ajax call.
(get he JS and HTML from Amr Magdy answer)

There are two ways:

A. You create a SESSION variable that acts as a counter. At each PHP call the counter increases and the PHP file gets the a specific line from the file.

B. You create a local variable (in JS file) that acts as a counter and sends it to the PHP file which uses it to grab a specific line from the file.

Here is A (.php part - JS is the same):

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["line_counter"]))
  $_SESSION["line_counter"]=0;

$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');
$counter=0;
$done = FALSE;

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE && !$done) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  if ($counter == $_SESSION["line_counter"]) {
    $names = $line;
    $data[] = $names[array_rand($names)];
    echo json_encode($data);
    $done=TRUE;
    $_SESSION["line_counter"]++;
  }
  $counter++;
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Here is B (.php part):

```
<?php
// check $_POST
$line_counter=0;
if (isset($_POST["line_counter"]) && is_numeric($_POST["line_counter"]))
    $line_counter=inval($_POST["line_counter"]);

$file = fopen('names.csv', 'r');
$counter=0;
$done = FALSE;

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE && !$done) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  if ($counter == $line_counter) {
    $names = $line;
    $data[] = $names[array_rand($names)];
    echo json_encode($data);
    $done=TRUE;
  }
  $counter++;
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

(You also need to change the JS file for B):

- create a global variable (var line_counter);
- send the line_counter at each ajax call
- increase line_counter at each success response